# Getting traverse over DOM objects

Tags: html, dom

I try I have these:

```
<div>
<div class="faviconDiv">
<a class="linkBig link draggableTitle ui-draggable" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3mP34Uznyk">EREN TAKKAN PISAH - YouTube</a>
</div>
<div> 
24 Okt 2009 … Vote Down Reply. Share; Remove; Flag for spam; Block User; Unblock User. lagumu mba Eren mencerikan&#65279; tentang kehidupn cintaku ma dy … 
</div>
```

I can get the tag  however I need to get also the lowest div element. Ho to get there from ?

Also there is multiple of this block following to each there hence I cannot use id or class to get just the  element that I want.

Shortly, I must get the element by traversing over DOM

Comment: What "_lowest_ div element" does mean?

Comment: last div element, the bottom one...

Comment: It's still unclear what is your task and/or problem. Get all DIVs that are last childs or their parents?

Comment: Dear friend, I need to go to bottom <div> element that includes a text starts with "24Okt..", from the the <a> element. Actually I try to get that text from the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you could use:

```
/* Will contain "24 Okt 2009..." */
var text = document.querySelector('.faviconDiv').nextSibling.textContent;
```

Comment: It is ok but I have <a> DOM as a variable already and I need to get there from <a> DOM. Also I have to not use class attr. or id. Thanks anyway...

Comment: `var parentOfLink = a.parentNode;`. You apparently need to learn more about [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) basics in general.